# Grouping image by variation id in shopify graphql api?

Tags: shopify, shopify-api

I only get featured image of the variation id. But i want to get all additional image belong to variation id. Is this possible to get all additional images related to variation id in shopify graphql api.

```
  featuredImage{
        url
      }
      media(first: 5) {
        edges {
          node {
              preview {
                image {
                  url
                }
              }
          }
        }
      }
```